# Show / hide image function with remove classname

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following function to display the image on which the user clicks on in an above div.

In the event the user clicks again on the populated image (in the div), I would like to remove the image in the div and have the original image visible again.

```
<img id="<?php echo $id; ?>" src="img/.." url=".." name="..."  onClick="changeImage(this)"/>

 function changeImage(item) {
      var url_img = $(item).attr('url');
      var name_item = $(item).attr('name');
       var item_id = $(item).attr('id');
       document.getElementById('test').innerHTML += '<div style=\'display:inline-block\'><img src=' + url_img + ' url = '  + url_img +  '  onClick=document.getElementById(' + item_id + ').classname=\'\'; /> ' + name_item + '</div>';     
       $(item).toggleClass('hideitem');
}
```

.hideitem is a class with display:none;

The onClick event in the function does not work (I was trying to remove the classname) and I'm not able to remove the div image when it is clicked with the onClick event.

Would anyone have an idea to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: You're toggling the class of the image you click on, not the DIV where you're displaying the image.

Comment: BTW, why don't you use jQuery instead of `document.getElementById`?

Comment: @Barman, I don't know how to. I'm only playing with the class of the images here, not divs.

Comment: Click on the "edit" link below the question to update it.

Comment: And make use of auto-complete after @ so that you spell my name right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some missing quotes and stuff in your code.

For this HTML:

```
<img id="myImgID" src="http://placehold.it/350x150" url="http://placehold.it/150x150" name="Example Dot Com" onClick="javascript:changeImage(this)" />
<div id="test">
    <p>this is only a test</p>
</div>
```

This JS:

```
changeImage = function (item) {
    var $item = $(item),
        $test = $('#test'),
        url_img = $item.attr('url'),
        name_item = $item.attr('name'),
        newDiv = $('<div/>').css('display', 'inline-block').text(name_item),
        newImg = $('<img/>').attr({'src':url_img, 'url':url_img})
            .click(function(e){$item.removeClass('hideitem')}).prependTo(newDiv);

    $test.append(newDiv)
    $item.toggleClass('hideitem');
}
```

[**See it in action here**](http://jsfiddle.net/te6uLvyw/)

Comment: Thanks, but when a 150x150 image is created, the 350px image is still there. And when clicking on a 150x150 image, the 150 image is still there too. I'm trying to have a show/hide system here (ie. when you click on the 350px img, the 150px img is shown and the 350px disappears, and vice versa).
@Ted, sure thanks

Comment: @carlos519 I adjusted the answer and the linked demo fiddle to fix it

Comment: @carlos519 -- just realized i forgot the text--added it to answer and demo